# Swift Fatal error: Index out of range (out of bounds index)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Hello I am trying to learn swift. I have a little experience with javascript so i tried modeling this loop in the same manner i usually do. The function actually outputs what its supposed to but I keep getting an error message and I am unsure of what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
let dir: [String] = ["north", "east", "south", "west"]
var num = dir.count
func move(){
    for i in 0 ... num{
        var holder = dir[i]
        switch holder{
        case "north":
            print("you've moved north")
        case "east":
            print("you've moved east")
        case "south":
            print("you've moved south")
        case "west":
            print("you've moved west")
        default:
            print("where you going?")
        }
        if i == 3{
            print("round the world")
        }

    }
}

move()
```

i get this error on the last line "move()"

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
>   (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).

this is what outputs to the console:

> you've moved north
>
> you've moved east
>
> you've moved south
>
> you've moved west
>
> round the world
>
> Fatal error: Index out of range: file
>   /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1103.2.25.8/swift/stdlib/public/core/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift,
>   line 444

Comment: `num = dir.count` gives 4 as that is the number of elements in the array. But you loop from element zero (correct) up to element 4 (which doesn’t exist) Use `0..<num` as Ashish demonstrates to loop from zero to one less than num.

Comment: For better understanding, you can go-through Swift official documentation i.e https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/GuidedTour/GuidedTour.html

Comment: Since you are a beginner in Swift, here's a suggestion - if you want to iterate over an array without really needing to know the index, use - for item in array { ... } - type of loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code trying to access 4th index due to you have used ... in loop control syntax. And 4th index not in array.

Here is some details about for swift loop.

```
for index in 0...4 {
 ...
}
```

The above snippet says, iterate over the range starting at 0 and inclusive of 4 i.e from 0–4

If you do not want 4 included, you use this called the half-open range operator (..<).

```
for index in 0..<4 {
 ...
}
```

This would loop from 0 to 3 and stop execution.

Comment: I've voted this correct because of the in depth explanation! Totally understood why it broke and I think other newbies will to!

Comment: @sallycakes the correct approach is `for index in dir.indices {`

Answer (score 3):

In swift, there're more efficient ways to loop...but to better understand what you implemented...

I've updated your code...it will run properly.

```
let dir: [String] = ["north", "east", "south", "west"]
var num = dir.count
func move(){
    for i in 0..<num{
        var holder = dir[i]
        switch holder{
        case "north":
            print("you've moved north")
        case "east":
            print("you've moved east")
        case "south":
            print("you've moved south")
        case "west":
            print("you've moved west")
        default:
            print("where you going?")
        }
        if i == 3{
            print("round the world")
        }

    }
}

move()
```

Output :-

```
you've moved north
you've moved east
you've moved south
you've moved west
round the world
```

Happy Coding in Swift :-)

Comment: thank you so much; it did really help me understand the syntax! I've marked @MiteshPrajapati answer as correct because I think it will better help newbies like me understand why this error occurred

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let dir: [String] = ["north", "east", "south", "west"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         move()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func move(){
        for (index, element) in dir.enumerated() {
       //   print("Item \(index): \(element)")
            switch element{
                        case "north":
                            print("you've moved north")
                        case "east":
                            print("you've moved east")
                        case "south":
                            print("you've moved south")
                        case "west":
                            print("you've moved west")
                        default:
                            print("where you going?")
                        }
                        if index == 3{
                            print("round the world")
                        }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, here you are first taking count of the num which is here 4.

[image]